# $G$ has a bipartition $(X,Y)$, and matching $M$ so that $X$ is fully matched, show $\exists x \in X$ with all its edges belong to a maximal matching

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Firstly, it was clear to me that $M$ might not be a bipartite matching, as nodes within $X$ might be matched to one another.

But what will our approach be to prove the existence of a vertex with all edges belonging to one of the possibly many maximal matchings?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is a bipartition then $G$ is bipartite and $M$ will definitely be a bipartite matching.

Comment: Yes, but what if this matching is not $X \rightarrow Y$. it might be a bipartite matching for another bipartition $(X',Y')$

Comment: All neighbors of vertices in $X$ are in $Y$. If all vertices of $X$ are saturated by $M$ then their matching neighbors are all in $Y$. Whether $M$ saturates $X'$ for some other bipartition $(X',Y')$ is not known, nor is it relevant.